# When used in a view, MySQL function returns error, "ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)"

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

No matter what I do, I continue to receive the following error when attempting to select records from a view that calls the below function:

```
ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

Here is the function I am calling:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `bcc_subscribers`.`Fn_FormatPhone`(strTextFull VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS varchar(255) CHARSET utf8mb4
BEGIN

DECLARE strCleanText VARCHAR(255);
--
SET strCleanText = (strTextFull,' ','');
SET strCleanText = (strCleanText,'-','');
SET strCleanText = (strCleanText,'.','');
SET strCleanText = (strCleanText,'(','');
SET strCleanText = (strCleanText,')','');
    
IF SUBSTRING(strCleanText,1,1)='+' THEN
    SET strCleanText = SUBSTRING(strCleanText, 2, 255);
ELSEIF SUBSTRING(strCleanText,1,1)='1' THEN
    SET strCleanText = SUBSTRING(strCleanText,2,255);
END IF;

SET strCleanText = '(' + SUBSTRING(strCleanText, 1, 3) + ') ' + SUBSTRING(strCleanText, 4, 3) + '-' + SUBSTRING(strCleanText, 7, 4);

RETURN strCleanText;
END
```

I am then calling this function in the following view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED VIEW `bcc_subscribers`.`new_view` AS
select
    `id` AS `id`,
    `firstName` AS `firstName`,
    `lastName` AS `lastName`,
    `fn_FormatPhone`(phone)
   
from
    `bcc_subscribers`.`subscribers`
```

Everytime I attempt to run the view I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

After reading up on the error, the most common cause is a subquery that contains multiple columns but that is expected to return a single column. However, that's not the case here (as far I my novice skills can tell).  Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: What is `SET strCleanText = (strTextFull,' ','');` supposed to mean? I think you're missing the call to `REPLACE()`. `SET strCleanText = REPLACE(strTextFull,' ','');`

Comment: `MySQL` doesn't use `+` for concatenation, it uses the `CONCAT()` function.

Comment: You should get the function working before working on the view that uses it.

Comment: You need to give an alias to the phone number column of the view.

Comment: The view you show queries the function `fn_phoneNumbers()`, but you show only your code for function `Fn_FormatPhone()`. Which one is it?

Comment: Thanks @Barmar - Thanks for pointing that out. I've been working on converting a script from T-SQL to MySQL and I thought I'd figured out the translation. The original statement was: 

```select @strCleanText=replace(@strTextFull,' ',")```

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d592a698b20cb404a7cd039ab4c7009b